# Importing an svg image in typescript

Tags: svg, typescript2.0

Using the following code as an example, which works perfectly, the typescript compiler is crying about the "`import logo from './images/logo.svg';`" statement. The app works perfectly when ran in the browser so I am not having any issues with functionality. I'd just like to get rid of the squiggly red line so I can clean up my directory viewer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import logo from './images/logo.svg';

interface Property {}
interface State {} 

export default class App extends React.Component<Property, State> { 
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <div className="App-header">
                    <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />                        
                </div>      
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: add declare module '*.svg' in any of your typing files. (.d.ts)

Comment: @SteveMcMeen could you add that as an answer so I can mark it answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add declare module '*.svg' in any of your typing files. (.d.ts)